# How do i get the uuid of a player in minecraft with nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, minecraft

I am working on a discord bot that gets information from a server. for this to work, i need the uuid of a minecraft player. I am using a dependency, but it is not working. Even if I enter a valid name, it still gives me this:
[code & output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpdVJ.png)

the string of numbers in the console is a character in minecraft named undefined... so yeah, if you see that my code isn't in the right data type (for example, it was supposed to be an integer instead of a string), please tell me. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Please add your code in code block. As you can see, you got `502 gateWay` error, so libery site API doesnt response

Comment: Hi @zachary as Cipher mention you should add your code and 'how you are calling' this export... And just to say, why you use a combination of async and promise chaining, no need for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send a request to:

https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/

This will give you the UUID of the specified Minecraft username.